# Point client domain to our subdomain

Tags: dns, cname

We are currently developing a CMS for our clients. We would like to host all their pages on our server like this:

https://www.example.com/client1website or https://www.example.com/client2website.

Is there a simple way to redirect content from https://www.example.com/client1website to https://www.theirdomain.com?

I know that Heroku or Wix work in a similar way, but I don't really know how to achieve it. Setting the CNAME for www to https://www.exmaple.com/client2website is probably not enough?

Comment: "Setting the CNAME for www to https://www.exmaple.com/client2website is probably not enough?" Specifically since CNAME allows aliasing a name to a different name, **NOT** to an URL...

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but in short you have to understand the difference between name resolution and URL handling. For name resolution, no matter which hostnames you use they need to resolve to an IP where a webserver is. It can be yours, or it can be your registrar/DNS provider one if they offer you a redirection service. Then that webserver needs to be configured to either show proper content for the hostname requested, or do an HTTP redirection, or be an HTTP reverse proxy. Once you split properly these 2 needs, things are simple, and documented A LOT

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy can do https://www.client1website.example.com to https://www.theirdomain.com

But otherwise they are going to need to stop at your server first since you are pointing them down into your directory

You can redirect using [status code 308](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308)

Comment: Hello, It's not about pointing to a directory. We need all traffic to go through our server. All sites would use the same database.

Comment: If someone go to https://www.exmaple.com/client1website/page1. We would like to run request on our server for page1 of the client1.

Comment: @FilipVojtíšek while having the user connect to https://www.theirdomain.com/page1 correct?

Comment: Exactly. Maybe there is no easy way to achieve this.

Comment: Ok I think this is called a [common gateway interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) if you are able to set up each client with this, then it would be actually pretty simple

Comment: Alternatively, they could just point their dns to you

Comment: @AnthonyL CGI is to run dynamic pages on webserver, this has almost nothing to do with HTTP redirects...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek It can be used as a simple way to redirect content from one system to another though right? a [picture](https://www.supportsages.com/sscontent/uploads/2014/10/cgi-diagram.gif) to help visualize

Comment: " It can be used as a simple way" CGI as a simple way to do HTTP redirect? You are kidding right? This can be achieved with one line in Apache configuration file, see the Redirect statement. You don't need any programming language for that. And I did "CGI" applications 30 years ago, so, thanks, but I kind of know what it is.

Comment: Sounds like it. Sending content from an inner server equals HTTP Redirect. You learn something new every day.